# I want to detect alert view when scratching particular area of image

Tags: ios, objective-c

[STScratchView](https://github.com/SebastianThiebaud/STScratchView) : i have used this github demo for scratchView.

> I cant find particular area of scratching image.
>   when i scratch particular area of image and then call event like alertview.
>   scratching image is display over UILabel.
>   now my problem is when i starting scratch the image and when display UILable text then automatically call event like alertview.
>   so please help me what can i do for that?

Comment: not getting what you are asking ? ask questions like someone can understand and can help !!!

Comment: first of all you open STScratchView. then after in this demo just scratch area and show UILabel auto generated text. so my question is how can i show alert after scratch particular area which show only text of label.

Comment: understand or not?